# value not returing in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

i have a login form but the val() function is not working any help please help 
whats the error ??
 { this is just to allow submission dont see this is just to allow submission dont see this is just to allow submission dont see this is just to allow submission dont see this is just to allow submission dont see

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="">
    <input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First name" >
    <input id="lname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" placeholder="age">
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address / City">
    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="state ">
    <select name="country">
    <option value="-">Country</option>
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="usa">usa</option>
    <option value="newzealand">New-zealand</option>
    </select>
    <select name="interest">
    <option value="-">Fitness Interest</option>
    <option value="Weightloss">Weight loss</option>
    <option value="GainMuscle">Gain muscle</option>
    <option value="Dailyfitness">Daily fitness</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="sjsj">
</form>
<div id="banner">
</div>


</div>
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
         var fname = $('#lname').val();
         $('#sjsj').click(function(e) {
             alert(fname);
             e.preventDefault();
             $('#form')[0].reset();
         });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var fname = $('#lname').val();` move it inside the click event handler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/djrz6z3f/1/

Comment: `var fname = $('#lname').val();` you should really check this or you'll get confused... you put lname value to fname

Comment: thank you workss !!!! yipeee